# AXLSX formula for date shows only number signs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, axlsx

I am trying to work on a spreadsheet for an in-house application.  So far it is going pretty well.  While, probably not the worst thing that can happen, since it can be fixed by clicking on the cell and pressing enter, it is annoying to me.

I am using the AXLSX gem on Ruby-On-Rails 3.2.13.

My format code is:

```
date_cell = s.add_style :format_code=>"mm/dd/yy", :bg_color=>"ffffcc"
```

My cell has, in the array, the formula:

```
"=E#{row.to_s}+G#{row.to_s}*30"
```

I've tried adding formula_values, but with no avail:

```
 :formula_values=>["05/01/12","05/01/12",...] # all the same
```

I've done the following:

- Checked to make sure the format is being applied to that specific cell
- Made sure the formula_values were filled by output to the log file

I'm not sure if I am missing a step or what.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @pnuts from what I understand the AXLSX gem is supposed to figure that out automatically.  It could be though if I didn't understand it correct.  But, what I don't understand is it auto-adjusts after hitting enter.  I'll check it out tomorrow at work.

Comment: @pnuts you were correct it wasn't wide enough for the width ```sheet.column_widths *args``` fixed the problem.  If you write an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @pnuts It is true it may be too localized.  I'm going to leave it here for awhile because the formula that is being used is used in depreciation tables.  This one is an in-house developed asset management system and I could see similar projects running into the same problem.  The actual formula would be: date of purchase + life span (in months) * 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without wrapping, when a cell is not wide enough for its content it usually spills over (if text) or fills with hash signs (if numeric) – or widens itself to suit. However it seems that if the column width has already been adjusted the automatic widening does not repeat. Anyway, it was column width that was the problem and I understand this was solved with `sheet.column_widths *args` - so all’s well than ends well.

Comment: Just looked at the source code for another issue with AXLSX and found out that if the value is a formula the AXLSX does not apply it's auto_width method.